# Apache HTTP - Exclude specific file from Include directive

Tags: apache, http, include, httpd.conf

In Apache HTTP is it possibile to exclude a specific file from Include directive?

Example:

```
conf.d
  - a
  - b
  - c
```

Pseudo code to include a, c but no b

```
Include conf.d/*[!b]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. But you can glob the thing. Change to:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

And then:

```
mv conf.d/b.conf conf.d/b.disabled
service apache2 reload
```